# nginx sub-subdomain wildcard

Tags: regex, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm having troubles setting up a reverse proxy for a sub-subdomain using nginx.

I'm trying to create a configuration which allows me to resolve:

```
a.b.example.com ==> a.local.host.lan
```

Currently i am able to resolve it as follows:

```
a.b.example.com ==> a.b.local.host.lan
```

with following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(.*)\.b.example\.com$;
    set $servername $1;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$servername.local.host.lan;
}
```

any idea how to tokenize the $servername variable so i can split **a** and **b**?

Comment: Do you mean capture the first and second parts before example.com ?

Comment: yes. I would atleast want to capture the "a" part.

Comment: "a" being what, the first segment before the dot ? `^([^.]*).*?\.b.example\.com$`