# Nginx proxy_pass from *.local.domain.com to *.domain.com

Tags: nginx, proxypass, wildcard-subdomain

I have 2 different dns records. One for `domain.com` that points at a public ip address (i.e. 93.184.216.34) and one for `local.domain.com` that points at the local ip address (i.e. 10.0.0.2) for computers on the same network to use.

I have the following configuration to proxy_pass the local subdomain to the naked domain which seems to work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    # ssl config here

    server_name local.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1/;
        set $non_local_host domain.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $non_local_host;
        proxy_redirect http://$non_local_host/ http://$host/;
        proxy_redirect https://$non_local_host/ https://$host/;
    }
}
```

But I also need subdomains to work. `foo.local.domain.com` should proxy to `foo.domain.com`, and `bar.baz.local.domain.com` should proxy to `bar.baz.domain.com`

I understand that I need to duplicate the above server block. Change `server_name` to `*.local.domain.com`, but not sure how to properly set `$not_local_host` to point at the right subdomain.

The closest similar questions are: [nginx sub-subdomain wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35543009/1248889), but that was in the opposite direction (and never answered), and this answer to [How can i pass subdomain as proxy_pass value in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31798936/1248889), but its for different domains (rather than subdomains) and it's some magic regex I don't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
map $host $non_local_host {
    ~^(.*\.)?local\.domain\.com    "${1}domain.com";
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    # ssl config here

    server_name .local.domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $scheme://127.0.0.1/;
        proxy_set_header Host $non_local_host;
        proxy_redirect http://$non_local_host/ http://$host/;
        proxy_redirect https://$non_local_host/ https://$host/;
    }
}
```

The `.local.domain.com` server name will match `local.domain.com` and any of it's subdomains.

If your site make use of cookies, you may also need a [`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) directive:

```
proxy_cookie_domain $non_local_host $host;
```